# Finding Min and Max Values in List Pattern in Python

Tags: python, function

I have a csv file and the data pattern like this:

[image]

I am importing it from csv file. In input data, there are some whitespaces and I am handling it by using pattern as above. For output, I want to write a function that takes this file as an input and prints the lowest and highest blood pressure. Also, it will return average of all mean values. On the other side, I should not use pandas.

I wrote below code blog.

```
bloods=open(bloodfilename).read().split("\n")
blood_pressure=bloods[4].split(",")[1]
pattern=r"\s*(\d+)\s*\[\s*(\d+)-(\d+)\s*\]"
re.findall(pattern,blood_pressure)

#now extract mean, min and max information from the blood_pressure of each patinet and write a new file called blood_pressure_modified.csv
pattern=r"\s*(\d+)\s*\[\s*(\d+)-(\d+)\s*\]"
outputfilename="blood_pressure_modified.csv"
# create a writeable file
outputfile=open(outputfilename,"w")

for blood in bloods:
    patient_id, blood_pressure=bloods.strip.split(",")
    mean=re.findall(pattern,blood_pressure)[0]
    blood_pressure_modified=re.sub(pattern,"",blood_pressure)
    print(patient_id, blood_pressure_modified, mean, sep=",", file=outputfile)
    
outputfile.close()
```

Output should looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Bit confusion here, so what exactly is the output you want here? Can you just share in the description above the sample output as well for each of the five rows you've given as sample input?

Comment: I have edited the question. But, Actually, 5 rows below is input. I am importing it from csv file. In input data, there are some whitespaces and I am handling it by using pattern as above. For output, I want to write a function that takes this file as an input and prints the lowest and highest blood pressure. Also, it will return average of all mean values.

Comment: Okay, so I've got a very simple solution. Am not sure if I am covering all your nitty gritty issues here. Not even using regex. Let me know if it works. Posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple kind of answer to this. No regex, pandas or anything.
Let me know if this is working. I can try making it work better for any case it doesn't work.

```
bloods=open("bloodfilename.csv").read().split("\n")

means = []

'''
Also, rather than having two list of mins and maxs, 
we can have just one and taking min and max from this 
list later would do the same trick. But just for clarity I kept both.
'''
mins = []
maxs = []
for val in bloods[1:]:     #assuming first line is header of the csv
    mean, ranges = val.split(',')[1].split('[')
    
    means.append(int(mean.strip()))
    
    first, second = ranges.split(']')[0].split('-')
    mins.append(int(first.strip()))
    maxs.append(int(second.strip()))
    
print(f'the lowest and the highest blood pressure are: {min(mins)} {max(maxs)} respectively\naverage of mean values is {sum(means)/len(means)}')
```

You can also create functions to perform small small strip stuff. That's usually a better way to code. I wrote this in bit hurry, so don't mind.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I got an error. Because there are some white spaces between in some characters in some rows. If I can delete these white spaces, your code is running.

Comment: That can be handled as well. If you want, you can the error case in the above sample input and I can change the code to handle that. Suit yourself @ds_ds. Have a nice day otherwise.

Hey btw, can you accept this answer? And thanks for the upvote btw.

Comment: By the way,  the reason of error is about different issue. I have handled it. Thank you! Your answer works!

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe this could help with your question,

Suppose you have a CSV file like this, and want to extract only the min and max values,**

```
SN  Number
1   135[113-166]
2   140[110-155]
3   132[108-180]
4   40[130-178]
5   133[118-160]
```

Then,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_FILE_NAME.csv")
results = df['YOUR_NUMBER_COLUMN'].apply(lambda x: x.split("[")[1].strip("]").split("-"))


with open("results.csv", mode="w") as f:
    f.write("MIN," + "MAX")
    f.write("\n")
    for i in results:
        f.write(str(i[0]) + "," + str(i[1]))
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()
```

**After you ran the snippet after without any errors then in your current working directory their should be a file named `results.csv` Open it up and you will have the results**